# Reproject Geoserver layer in Web Mercator Mapbox frontend

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wms, mapbox-gl-js, web-mercator

I am looking to visualise live satellite imagery in a Mapbox GL JS Fronend. There exists a [Geoserver instance](https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/SAT_EU_RGB/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) which has exactly the resource I want to use. However, the layer is in the wrong EPSG. What is the easiest way to link my Frontend (Web Mercator, EPSG: 3857) to the output of the Geoserver (EPSG: 4326) without doing any reproduction by hand?

Comment: The service is defo working to give a satellite image when requesting EPSG:3857, so the issue appears to be in your request.  Can you sniff out what request is actually made?

Comment: Interesting, I had just naively replaced the EPSG in a request which worked with 4326: https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3&request=GetMap&layers=dwd:SAT_EU_RGB&bbox=-5.00,40.76,20.90,55.01&width=512&height=418&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image%2Fjpeg

This does not return anything but does not give an Error too. So the difference to the working request is in the Bounding Boxes which I naively did not change.

Comment: In your example request you have `version=1.3&` needs to be `version=1.3.0&` or some other valid version number (1.1.1, 1.1.0...) .  You have `srs=EPSG:3857&` but for a version 1.3.0 request you need to use `crs=EPSG:3857&`.  You must specify a `styles` parameter even if it's empty (to get the default) `styles&` or otherwise indicate the styles to use in an SLD or SLD_BODY parameter .   The BBOX is specified in units of the CRS (minx,miny,maxx,maxy). In version 1.3.0, X is the first listed axis and Y the second axis, see EPSG registry for details http://www.epsg-registry.org/  for axis order.

Comment: In EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4258 the units are decimal degrees (lat/lon), in the range +/- 90,+/-180.  In EPSG:3857 units are metres (easting,northing) in the range +/-20026376,+/-20048966.  Your request BBOX `5.00,40.76,20.90,55.01`, isn't in error (it's in bounds) it's just taken as a very small area near the equator

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

The GeoServer service supports EPSG:3857, so you can call it directly.  The GetCapabilities has for the root layer:

```
<Layer>
    <Title>DWD GeoServer WMS</Title>
    <Abstract>This is the Web Map Server of DWD.</Abstract>
    <!-- Limited list of EPSG projections: -->
    <CRS>EPSG:3044</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:3045</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:3413</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:4258</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:4839</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:25832</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:25833</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:31467</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:31468</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:1000001</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:1000004</CRS>
```

These CRS are available to all sub-layers.

You can test it works by using QGIS (works for me), or just by hand-cranking a GetMap request using the stated extent for the CRS like:

> https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/SAT_EU_RGB/ows?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetMap&format=image/png&style&layers=SAT_EU_RGB&CRS=EPSG:3857&version=1.3.0&BBOX=-6011097,2631938,6010897,13852635&width=800&height=600&

Gives [image: GetMap response using EPSG:3857]

Comment: I also noticed this in GetCapabilities and tried requesting some image resources in EPSG:3857. However, the server only delivers empty replies to requests not containing EPSG 4326 or EPSG 4258.